# Past Simple/ Present Perfect

Tags: tense

Is it correct to say

> "I've missed this programme but I've watched another informative programme"

Should I say 'but I've watched...' or 'but I watched...'

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to cast the first clause in the present perfect?

Comment: @StoneyB I thought the same. Writing *I missed* (...) *but I've watched* (...) shows more relevance.

Comment: The sentence is somewhat odd. "this" is the present tense. So  "I've missed that programme but I've watched another informative programme."

Comment: I missed this programme but watched another informative programme.

Comment: @StoneyB Sorry to be a bumpkin but can you please explain to me what bumped tot he homepage by Community means? Thanks.

Comment: @Lambie 'bumped to the homepage' means it's been moved from the depths of history onto the ELL landing page--in effect, moved to or near the front of the queue of questions which visitors first encounter. "Community" I *think* means this action was taken by the site's software according to its own mysterious canons--perhaps it falls under ["randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), except this has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to me to use a perfect tense. Also, I assume you're talking about missing some form of educational or entertainment activity but instead viewed an alternative. You are using dialogue so the word **that** should replace **this**. (You are explaining you missed a specific programme in the past.) Using a comma to join two independent clauses connected by a conjunction is standard but not necessary. Finally, it is awkward to use the word **programme** twice; a pronoun would work nicely.

**"I missed that programme, but I watched another informative one."**

The phrase **a different,** could replace **another**, but you would be understood either way. The more correct methodology would be to use serial adjectives "a different and informative one," which can be shortened by removing "and" and replacing with a comma.

Thus: **"I missed that programme, but I watched a different, informative one."**

Comment: If the people are looking at a TV schedule in which at least the first programme is listed, then *this* would be appropriate.

Comment: Granted. But only because you live in Oregon (heh, heh or have lived)

Comment: *Anaheim* Ducks! (National Hockey League)...

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence you do not need to use present perfect tense. Because you are talking about the programme which you did not watch. It's better to use past tense for the first sentence.

> "I missed this programme but I watched another informative one."

Also, in the second one you are talking about the programme which you watched. So, again it's better to use past tense, or you can use past perfect tense for the first sentece and past simple tense for the second one.

> "I had missed this programme but I watched another informative one."

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to use the present perfect tense if the time is not mentioned. If you talk about something you did yesterday or basically in the past use simple past. thanks.